# what is the best way to keep running a method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have to keep running a method for 24x7.Basically the 
application should process 40 data in every second, by using some thread.
i can use while or recursive call ling the same method. but in both process
the cpu uses getting too high almost 95-100 %. i can't use timer because
then the processing threads are not working properly. as per the provided solution
many people talk to use the while with thread sleep. but if i use thread sleep
then it getting delay in every iteration. i am using c# 4.0.

my question: is there any better solution to reduce the cpu uses?

the main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
     {
    while(true)
    {
      processData();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    // here i use a 1 second sleep just for give a breath of CPU.
    //But this one second sleep make me delay for enter data processing.
    // I am looking for a better solution that no sleep time will use and CPU usages will getting low.
    }
     }

//Method should run always

static string processData()
{
  {
// Open and close threads  to process the data in every second.
  }

 // processData(); // it can be used for recursive method calling
}
```

Comment: `but if i use thread sleep then it getting delay in every iteration` - Remove `Thread.Sleep` ???

Comment: Where is the data you are processing coming from?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `Thread.Sleep`.  Maybe you're not using it in the best place?  For example, if your code is looping constantly and executing about 10 times per second but you only need it to execute about once per second, then just sleep for 1 second in between each iteration.  Why is a 1 second delay causing a problem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In his current code, wouldn't the other threads continue to work during the 1s of sleep?  It sounds like he wants the 1s for the threads to do their work before resetting.

Comment: Why not use a time together with a dispatcher to return to the main thread on each call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but if i use thread sleep then it getting delay in every iteration. i am using c# 4.0.

You can use [`Thread.Sleep(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx), which indicates:

> that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  while(true)
  {
    processData();
    Thread.sleep(0);
  }
}
```

This will allow the thread to give up some processing to other threads, prevent it from using 100% of the CPU, but still allow it to run at nearly full speed.

Note that using any delay, while it will reduce the overall CPU usage, *will* slow down the total throughput.  The only way to maximize throughput would be allow it to spin non-stop, which of course will keep the CPU usage very high.

Comment: thanks for your comments. but, it's not reduce my CPU usages.

Comment: @riad You can sleep for any duration, and it should reduce the total usage - if nothing else is running on the system, using 0 will likely not change the total usage (but it won't hurt to use 100% CPU in that case).  If that's not the case, try using `Thread.Sleep(1)` or `Thread.Sleep(100)` to delay for shorter periods of time instead of a full second...

Comment: thanks. could you please suggest any article about this detail?or any link or post?

Comment: could you please suggest that if i use GC.Collect(); just after the method calling then the performance will increase? like:while (true)
                {
                    
                    sendMT();
                    GC.Collect();
                    Thread.Sleep(0);
                    
                }

Comment: @Riad `GC.Collect` will likely *decrease* your performance.  It's also a very bad idea for many other reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Using a System.Threading.Timer you are able to tell it when to next execute, e.g:

```
System.Threading.Timer myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(~~~)
```

inside myTimer callback:

```
myTimer.Change(nextRunTime, newInterval);
```

This will run the code next in nextRunTime, and the interval will become newInterval.

More information on the "Change" method available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hs7492w.aspx

And on System.Threading.Timer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Enjoy :)

Apologies if I'm being presumptuous, I'm of the impression that the reason you won't use a Timer is because there is always a fixed delay, but using this method you can adjust the delay each time it runs.

Anyways, if you're having issues with the Timer not processing correctly, can you share what exactly is going wrong there? May be able to help with that, and in the end use a Timer or similar.

Comment: basically, i already try to use timer in many ways. but it's getting problem to execute my code properly. getting problem to open and close threads properly and lot other issues.So, i already decide not to use timer in that case.Many thanks for your suggestions. But timer is not a appropriate solution in my case.

Comment: Alright, apologies if I wasted your time with this answer. I'll see if I can find any other ideas, I've played a lot with this kind of thing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        var beginTime = DateTime.Now;
        processData();
        var duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract( beginTime );

        // if you want to run 40 times per second,
        //  you need to spend 1000/40 = 25ms per iteration
        var sleepDuration = (int)(25 - duration.TotalMilliseconds);

        if( 0 < sleepDuration )
        {
            Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
        }
    }
 }
```

Edit: as suggested in another answer, you could use the `Timer` class if your `processData()` method is thread safe

Comment: is their any way to reduce the CPU usages without using the thread sleep?basically i dont want to runn the method 40 times. this processData will run when it complete it's inner thread's word. the inner thread process 40 data per second. which i don't mentioned here.If i use the thread sleep then the CPU usages become low for that moment.but it's again getting higher when code goes to thread block.

Comment: The `Timer` class abstracts that away for you but any running process that isn't using 100% of the CPU is ultimately sleeping

Answer (score 0):

this below code can be a appropriate solution in this case. For more detail please check this [link](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/08/22/priorityinduced-starvation-why-sleep1-is-better-than-sleep0-and-the-windows-balance-set-manager/).

```
             uint loops = 0;
                while (true)
                {                    
                    if (Environment.ProcessorCount == 1 || (++loops % 100) == 0)
                    {
                        processData();
                        Thread.Sleep(1);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        processData();
                        Thread.SpinWait(20);

                    }
                }
```